# How can i resolve dupicate class error in my project

Tags: duplicates, dependencies

I have just created a new project in android studio with the **bottom navigation views activity**. I have tried to build right away without adding anything but i get this error

```
!Duplicate Class Found
Duplicate class kotlin.collections.jdk8.CollectionsJDK8Kt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.20) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.6.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.6.21)
```

Can anyone help me on how to resolve it

my dependencies are as below

```
dependencies {
    implementation libs.appcompat
    implementation libs.material
    implementation libs.constraintlayout
    implementation libs.lifecycle.livedata.ktx
    implementation libs.lifecycle.viewmodel.ktx
    implementation libs.navigation.fragment
    implementation libs.navigation.ui
    testImplementation libs.junit
    androidTestImplementation libs.androidx.test.ext.junit
    androidTestImplementation libs.espresso.core
}
```

i really cant see where the problem is coming from because all of the files where auto-generated its a new project.

Comment: `kotlin-stdlib` and `kotlin-stdlib-jdk8` are standard library components & you seem have varying versions, which you can verify in `build.gradle` and ensure their compatibility with your dependecies. Clear the memory, restart IDE and Build your project. I would create a new project if the error persists.

Comment: @Raky , its already a new project , everything there was auto generated and creating a new project made no changes, i tried playing around with the dependencies and i found the problem was resulting from using the **livedata and viewmodel dependencies**. if i remove them and also remove the imports and methods that use them, the project builds. but then the project will not be as i like

Comment: Please check the code in the Answer Cell below. I dunno If I can help more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution that works, the solution was add a contraints block to **dependecies** in **build.gradle** as shown below

```
dependencies {
constraints {
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.8.0") {
        because("kotlin-stdlib-jdk7 is now a part of kotlin-stdlib")
    }
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.8.0") {
        because("kotlin-stdlib-jdk8 is now a part of kotlin-stdlib")
    }
}
implementation libs.appcompat
implementation libs.material
implementation libs.constraintlayout
implementation libs.lifecycle.livedata.ktx
implementation libs.lifecycle.viewmodel.ktx
implementation libs.navigation.fragment
implementation libs.navigation.ui
testImplementation libs.junit
androidTestImplementation libs.androidx.test.ext.junit
androidTestImplementation libs.espresso.core
```

}

this prevents the Kotlin grdadle plugin from using duplicate classes from the different versions

Answer (score 0):

Please update your `build.gradle` as follows

```
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy {
              eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
                if (details.requested.group == 'androidx.lifecycle' && details.requested.name.contains('lifecycle')) {
                    details.useVersion '2.3.1' // Put your version number
                }
            }
        }
    }

   dependencies {
    implementation libs.appcompat
    implementation libs.material
    implementation libs.constraintlayout
    implementation libs.lifecycle.livedata
    implementation libs.lifecycle.viewmodel
    implementation libs.navigation.fragment
    implementation libs.navigation.ui
    testImplementation libs.junit
    androidTestImplementation libs.androidx.test.ext.junit
    androidTestImplementation libs.espresso.core
}
```

Look at the comments in the above configuration. This is only a wild guess to assist you.